# How can I bind data to an ASP.NET Web Form report?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I have a report 'defined' as a Web Form (aspx). It is divided into what I have classed as sections, where each section has a heading, optional description, and then either tables (GridViews), charts (user controls with asp:Chart controls), or details (in e.g. HTML *definition lists*).  Currently the report is explicitly populated, i.e. code in Page_Load assigns the DataSource property and calls DataBind on GridViews and Charts, explicitly assigns scalar values to label controls for detail sections.

I would like to build a single data set type object (initially an untyped DataSet, but eventually any object graph) and assign this to a DataSource property on the whole report, and call the report's DataBind method. This should delegate data binding to report sections, e.g. I set the DataMember property on my report's PropertyDetails section to "PropertyDetails", so that the PropertyDetails section renders report values from the "PropertyDetails" data table in my big report data set.

How should I structure my Report page (or Control) to facilitate this? I would ideally like a declarative structure similar to the GridView or DataList control, but without a repeating element, i.e. each report section is different, unlike 'rows' in a GridView or DataList; in fact more like Columns in a GridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wrapping your data into a DataSet simply inherit your Report from the [BaseDataBoundControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.aspx) class.

Then you can DataBind to it directly.

Comment: +1 for the nice pointer @user357320, but I'm also actually looking for advice of structuring the report, e.g. so individual sections get bound to different members of the master data set etc.

Comment: When databinding the Report (which inherits from BaseDataBoundControl) would DataBind it would run through each Section(which would also inherit from BaseDataBoundControl).  Each Section would have a "DataName"(**not** DataMember) that the Report would use to set the DataSource(by reading the DataName table from the DB and create a DataSet) of the Section before DataBinding it.  I have used this method successfully in a dynamic form entry application before.

Comment: Thanks, busy building an example report with trivial data to get a feel for this.